# How do I create an MongoDB Atlas database using mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, mongodb-atlas

I'm using mongoengine in python and I cannot get it to create a database to connect to. I know how to use the connect function but I forgot how to create the DB or maybe they changed it?

I have all my collections set up as classes and I have a object with the .save() which causes this error.
Object:

```
Product(
    name='Bitcoin',
    symbol='BTC',
    productId=1,
    amounts=['0.0005', '0.001', '0.002', '0.003', '0.005'],
    logo='btc.png',
    front='front.png',
    back='back.jpg',
    desc='p2p network'
).save()
```

Error:

> mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: ValidationError (Product:None) (String value did not match validation regex 1.String value did not match validation regex

Answer (score 0):

Databases get created automatically in MongoDB when you connect to it so this shouldn't be a problem.

The error you attached isn't related to that, that error suggest that something in the document that you try to save doesn't pass validation.